# Chrome for iPad retina icons

Tags: retina-display, apple-touch-icon, chrome-ios

I have noticed that while retina `apple-touch-icons` work in Safari, Chrome for iPad seems to only render the lowest resolution icon. The very same page as it appears in Safari and Chrome for iPad respectively:

[image: Icon seems great in Safari]
[image: Icon appears blurry in Chrome as it does not use the hi-res version]

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{$cdnUrl}/images/apple/apple-touch-icon-57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="{$cdnUrl}/images/apple/apple-touch-icon-57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="{$cdnUrl}/images/apple/apple-touch-icon-72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="{$cdnUrl}/images/apple/apple-touch-icon-114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="{$cdnUrl}/images/apple/apple-touch-icon-144.png">
```

Is there a way to tell Chrome for iPad which version of the icon it should use?

Comment: Silly question: what do you expect Chrome for iOS to do with this icon? When bookmarking, Chrome displays a miniature of the page. And it cannot add a bookmark to the home screen (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392063?hl=en-GB)

Comment: I expect Chrome to render the retina version instead of the standard resolution version in the Chrome bookmarks view.

Comment: Damn! I was looking at the "most recent" screen, which present miniatures. You are right, bookmarks come with icons. I observe the same 57x57 icon on my iPad Mini, despite of the 8 pictures I declared in the code (from 57x57 to 152x152). Yet, this is not a Retina device.